# Issue With Delayed Expansion In Batch Code

Tags: batch-file

I am running into an issue where I have a complete directory listing of a computer (located in the text file shown below).

The issue appears in cases where the directory listing contains special characters such as "! or &".  When that issue occurrs, the filename is parsed such that those special characters are omitted (thus causing issues with leveraging those variables to compute other sub-tasks).  Below is a snapshot of the code.  Please advise as to how I might proceed.

Note that within the text file might be paths such as:

C:\Windows!temp!\file.txt
C:\Windows\file.txt

This will parse as:

C:\Windows\temp\file.txt (without quotes)
C:\Windows\file.txt

---

### code snip

```
 for /f "delims=?" %%a in (dir.txt) do (
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 set filepath=%%a
 )
 call :subproc1
 )
 goto :proc2

 :subproc1
      echo !filepath!
      endlocal
      goto :eof

 :proc2 
      continue with script here
```

Comment: why do you have two closing brackets after the for?

Answer (score 1):

You are toggling delayed expansion on too early, and there is no need for the subroutine.

```
for /f "delims=?" %%a in (dir.txt) do (
  set filepath=%%a
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  echo !filepath!
  endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=?" %%a in (dir.txt) do (
    setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
    (echo(%%a)
    endlocal
)
endlocal

goto :proc2


:proc2 
     echo -------end
```

[the Jeb's](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=6701#p6701)  [trick...](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb)